# How to install same file to multiple locations (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to figure out how to copy files to multiple locations with Inno Setup installer.

```
[Files]
Source: "myfolder\*" DestDir: {multipe dirs?}
```

Basically I have a function `GetInstallDirs()` that looks for all the keys in a registry location and form an array for with the plugin install path and returns an array of directories. Instead of adding a line for each directory, is there a way `DestDir` takes multiple directories?

Answer (score 3):

So you wanted to use `DestDir: "{code:GetInstallDirs}"`?

The `DestDir` can point to a single folder only.

You have to create more entries in `[Files]` section, if you need to install the same file to multiple folders. Note that Inno Setup will [compile the source file only once to the installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29392545/850848).

I'm not aware of an easy way to create the multiple entries programmatically.

You could create "a lot" of entries likes:

```
[Files]
Source: "myfolder*"; DestDir: "{code:GetInstallDirs|1}"; Check HasInstallDir(1)
Source: "myfolder*"; DestDir: "{code:GetInstallDirs|2}"; Check HasInstallDir(2)
Source: "myfolder*"; DestDir: "{code:GetInstallDirs|3}"; Check HasInstallDir(3)
...
```

You can create a large list of such entries using Inno Setup preprocessor.

```
#define EntryI

#sub AddEntry

Source: "myfolder*"; DestDir: "{code:GetInstallDirs|{#EntryI}}"; \
    Check: HasInstallDir({#EntryI})

#endsub 

#for {EntryI = 1; EntryI <= 100; EntryI++} AddEntry
```