# Using multiple DLL files in Inno Setup where there are duplicates

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to understand how Inno Setup compiles multiple files of the same name.

I have seen some information about this but given the following:

```
Source: "*.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "..\SomeOtherPath1\*.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\OtherLibrary1"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "..\SomeOtherPath2\*.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\OtherLibrary2"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

We know that the folder folders will contain some duplicate DLLs (which as far as I am aware at the moment have the same version numbers). Does the compiler embed all of the duplicates because the source folders are different?

Up until now I had been using the preprocessor to selectively include the duplicates, but if the compiler can handle it automatically then I could use the simplified script above.

Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the compiler embed all of the duplicates because the source folders are different?

Yes. Only if multiple `[Files]` section entries point to the same file (same path), Inno Setup will [(by default) merge those entries](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_mergeduplicatefiles).

Were it not so, my answer to this (yours) question would not be as complicated:
[Do not include duplicate files multiple times in the Inno Setup installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49646920/850848)